# Implement method in another project

Tags: c#

Is it possible to declare a method's class in a project and implement in another ? Something like :

```
namespace projectA
{
    Class A
    {
        void toImplement()
        {
            //TODO
        }
        void print()
        {
              toImplement();
        }
    }
}
namespace projectB
{
    A.toImplement()
    {
        // print “projectB"
    }
}
namespace projectC
{
    A.toImplement()
    {
        // print “projectC"
    }
}
```

I don't want to create a new class with inheritance, because I want to use the method in class A. But if I define the method in a project K, the method will do the same that if I call from project B.

Comment: Maybe you could make `A` abstract and implement a concrete class in `projectB`. Or you could use extensions methods. Or an interface, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an abstract method, but it will have to be `public` to be accessible in another project:

```
namespace projectA
{
    public abstract Class A
    {
        public abstract void toImplement();
    }
}

namespace projectB
{
    public Class B : A
    {
        public override void toImplement()
        {
            //Implement here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or he could make it `virtual` as another option. Depends on the implementation

Comment: It there a way to do something like without create a new class ?

Comment: This is how you do this in object-oriented programming. When you create a class in an assembly, it has to be complete. The only way an incomplete class is possible, is when you mark it abstract. Creating another class is almost never a problem in this case, because `B` is fully assignable to `A`. That means, everywhere you use `A`, you can use `B`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an Extension function see MSDN: [Extension Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

For just adding methods to it, - as you described in your second code example - you could use a partial class

```
public static class B_Extensions
{
   public static void SetString(this A a, string s)
   {
      a.Astring = s;
   }
}

public class A
{
   public string Astring { get; set; }
}
// In any other class
private void DoSomething()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.SetString("Something");
}
```

Partial Class: - put those in the same project

```
 public partial class A
 {
    public void SetString(string s)
    {
       Astring = s;
    }
 }

 public partial class A
 {
     public string Astring { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Extension methods might be a solution, but they won't have access to protected class members.

Comment: Is there a way with this to define the setString in class A (to use it on method) but define in other project ? (see my edit)

Comment: @JackyDoe You meen you want to override it in a different project? To make it clear for me: Do you use `A`, as a kind of an assembly - so you have three projects in one solution? Or do you use all of your three "projects as different namespaces" in one Project?

Comment: @TripleEEE I have a solution with 3 projects. Project A is a library, B and C are applications. ProjectA have to print logs. But depending on B or C it's not the same way (console or file). I want to call 'toImplement' in projectA. But projectB modifys the method to write in a file. ProjectC modifys to write in console. (hope to be clear, sorry for bad english)

Comment: @JackyDoe - your english is perfectly fine - mine isn't that much better ;) Well - if you want to do something like this, I'd rather work with a switch-case, maybe an enum for deciding what to do, and if needed provide the filename that needs be written to. This would be a clearer way to go in my opinion

Comment: Thank you for help. Finally I'll choose the solution with "strategy pattern". It avoids to rename my class. But your solution is fine for another project of mine

Answer (score 0):

So my guess is the reason you don't want to make `A` abstract and implement it in the other projects is because you want to be able to do `new A()` in the library.

In this case, the solution therefore, is to use the Factory Pattern.

You make the method abstract, and you declare a factory interface.

```
namespace projectA {
    Class A
    {
        abstract void toImplement();
    }

    Interface AFactory
    {
        A create()
    }
}
```

Then in your project that uses this you have your implementation of `A` and make a factory.

```
namespace projectB
{
    Class RealA extends A
    {
        void toImplement() { does stuff }
    }

    Class RealAFactory implements AFactory
    {
        A create() { return new RealA() }
    }
}
```

You now just need to pass the factory to the library when initalising it or at some logically point in time. Now `projectA` can get a new instance of `RealA` whenever it needs from `RealAFactory`.